# Webcam and hotspot concurrent access?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a webcam that broadcasts it's own SSID for direct connection without a router, as well as a mobile hotspot.  Is there any way I can have my PC connected to both concurrently?

Webcam: MiWa MW3
Mobile: Stock KB2007 Unlocked, on Verizon
PC: Win11 Pro x64
`MSInfo32.exe` §Network

```
System Information report written at: 01/31/23 13:21:13
System Name: HC-IDEAPAD
[Adapter]

Item    Value   
Name    [00000000] Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter   
Adapter Type    Not Available   
Product Type    Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter  
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   ROOT\KDNIC\0000 
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   0   
Service Name    kdnic   
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    Yes 
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address Not Available   
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\KDNIC.SYS (6.1.0.0, 69.33 KB (70,992 bytes), 5/6/2022 9:19 PM)  
        
Name    [00000001] Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz    
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz   
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A0F0&SUBSYS_00748086&REV_20\3&11583659&1&A3    
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   1   
Service Name    Netwtw10.   
IP Address  
IP Subnet   
Default IP Gateway
DHCP Enabled    Yes 
DHCP Server 
DHCP Lease Expires  1/31/2023 2:07 PM   
DHCP Lease Obtained 1/31/2023 1:07 PM   
MAC Address ‪8C:B8:7E:B3:F6:5F‬ 
Memory Address  0x522C000-0x522FFFF 
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967272  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967271  
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\NETWTW10.SYS (22.150.0.3, 4.72 MB (4,946,512 bytes), 9/2/2022 3:08 PM)  
        
Name    [00000002] Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller   
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller  
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_390817AA&REV_15\01000000684CE00000 
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   2   
Service Name    rt640x64    
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    Yes 
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address ‪E4:A8:DF:B5:9E:8B‬ 
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\RT640X64.SYS (10.50.511.2021, 1.10 MB (1,151,992 bytes), 2/24/2022 2:28 AM) 
        
Name    [00000003] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter   
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter  
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   {5D624F94-8850-40C3-A3FA-A4FD2080BAF3}\VWIFIMP_WFD\4&36705AF0&0&11  
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   3   
Service Name    vwifimp 
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    Yes 
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address ‪
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\VWIFIMP.SYS (10.0.22621.1, 84.00 KB (86,016 bytes), 5/6/2022 9:19 PM)   
        
Name    [00000004] Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) 
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)    
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   BTH\MS_BTHPAN\6&DBD3061&0&2 
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   4   
Service Name    BthPan  
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    Yes 
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address ‪
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\BTHPAN.SYS (10.0.22621.1, 156.00 KB (159,744 bytes), 5/6/2022 9:19 PM)  
        
Name    [00000005] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter   
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter  
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   {5D624F94-8850-40C3-A3FA-A4FD2080BAF3}\VWIFIMP_WFD\4&36705AF0&0&12  
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   5   
Service Name    vwifimp 
IP Address  192.168.137.1, fe80::616e:cac5:8fb2:3ac6    
IP Subnet   255.255.255.0, 64   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    No  
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address ‪8E:B8:7E:B3:F6:5F‬ 
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\VWIFIMP.SYS (10.0.22621.1, 84.00 KB (86,016 bytes), 5/6/2022 9:19 PM)   
        
Name    [00000006] WAN Miniport (SSTP)  
Adapter Type    Not Available   
Product Type    WAN Miniport (SSTP) 
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   SWD\MSRRAS\MS_SSTPMINIPORT  
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   6   
Service Name    RasSstp 
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    No  
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address Not Available   
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\RASSSTP.SYS (10.0.22621.1175, 120.00 KB (122,880 bytes), 1/19/2023 10:05 PM)    
        
Name    [00000007] WAN Miniport (IKEv2) 
Adapter Type    Not Available   
Product Type    WAN Miniport (IKEv2)    
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   SWD\MSRRAS\MS_AGILEVPNMINIPORT  
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   7   
Service Name    RasAgileVpn 
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    No  
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address Not Available   
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\AGILEVPN.SYS (10.0.22621.436, 140.00 KB (143,360 bytes), 7/23/2022 6:45 PM) 
        
Name    [00000008] WAN Miniport (L2TP)  
Adapter Type    Not Available   
Product Type    WAN Miniport (L2TP) 
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   SWD\MSRRAS\MS_L2TPMINIPORT  
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   8   
Service Name    Rasl2tp 
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    No  
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address Not Available   
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\RASL2TP.SYS (10.0.22621.1175, 148.00 KB (151,552 bytes), 1/19/2023 10:05 PM)    
        
Name    [00000009] WAN Miniport (PPTP)  
Adapter Type    Not Available   
Product Type    WAN Miniport (PPTP) 
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   SWD\MSRRAS\MS_PPTPMINIPORT  
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   9   
Service Name    PptpMiniport    
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    No  
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address Not Available   
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\RASPPTP.SYS (10.0.22621.891, 136.00 KB (139,264 bytes), 11/16/2022 7:45 PM) 
        
Name    [00000010] WAN Miniport (PPPOE) 
Adapter Type    Not Available   
Product Type    WAN Miniport (PPPOE)    
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   SWD\MSRRAS\MS_PPPOEMINIPORT 
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   10  
Service Name    RasPppoe    
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    No  
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address Not Available   
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\RASPPPOE.SYS (10.0.22621.1, 116.00 KB (118,784 bytes), 5/6/2022 9:19 PM)    
        
Name    [00000011] WAN Miniport (IP)    
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    WAN Miniport (IP)   
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   SWD\MSRRAS\MS_NDISWANIP 
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   11  
Service Name    NdisWan 
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    No  
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address ‪
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\NDISWAN.SYS (10.0.22621.1, 232.00 KB (237,568 bytes), 5/6/2022 9:19 PM) 
        
Name    [00000012] WAN Miniport (IPv6)  
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    WAN Miniport (IPv6) 
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   SWD\MSRRAS\MS_NDISWANIPV6   
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   12  
Service Name    NdisWan 
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    No  
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address ‪
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\NDISWAN.SYS (10.0.22621.1, 232.00 KB (237,568 bytes), 5/6/2022 9:19 PM) 
        
Name    [00000013] WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)   
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)  
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   SWD\MSRRAS\MS_NDISWANBH 
Last Reset  1/27/2023 3:46 AM   
Index   13  
Service Name    NdisWan 
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    No  
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address ‪
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\NDISWAN.SYS (10.0.22621.1, 232.00 KB (237,568 bytes), 5/6/2022 9:19 PM)
```

Comment: No, it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to two networks at the same time, you can use a bridge. This is typically used for two Wi-Fi networks, like if you require a stable, reliable connection.

I've never tested this with a webcam and Wi-Fi network, but it may be worth a shot. Please follow the steps below:

Go to Control Panel and click Network and Internet.
Click Network and Sharing Center.
On the left column, click change adapter settings.
Select both the connections and right click to see options. Click network bridge.
Windows will automatically make a network bridge, and you are done.

Comment: How would I go about getting the webcam to be enumerated as a connection in `ncpa.cpl`?  Currently I have to either connect to it's SSID broadcast directly or access it's stream via RTSP url, but in either case it doesn't show up as a network adapter entry?